# Substitute certain positions from matching line

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, awk

I'm trying to substitute certain positions from a line if the beginning is a given string. Here is an example of input file:

```
...
line1 with details 100 2566 1222
line2 with details 258 5874 5455
TOTAL text here    425 9589 8984
```

If `"TOTAL"` is found at the biginning of line, I'd like to substitute from position 20 to 27 by spaces:

```
...
line1 with details 100 2566 1222
line2 with details 258 5874 5455
TOTAL text here             8984
```

Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: is it same as "if total found, empty 4th and 5th fields" ?

Comment: @Kent Yes, as far as I am exporting a CSV file from a mysql query before creating the plain text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(TOTAL.\{14\}\).\{8\}\(.*\)/\1        \2/' <file>
```

This solution captures the first 19 chars, skips the following 8, and captures the rest of the line.

```
$ sed 's/\(TOTAL.\{14\}\).\{8\}\(.*\)/\1        \2/' <<EOF
...
line1 with details 100 2566 1222
line2 with details 258 5874 5455
TOTAL text here    425 9589 8984
EOF

...
line1 with details 100 2566 1222
line2 with details 258 5874 5455
TOTAL text here             8984
```

In case you can have either `TOTAL` or `SUMA_`, simply use:

```
sed 's/\(\(TOTAL\|SUMA_\).\{14\}\).\{8\}\(.*\)/\1        \3/' <file>
```

Comment: Thanks! Any easy way to work when finding "TOTAL" OR "SUMA_" to avoid using two lines of code?

Comment: @jm_ You're very welcome! I've added a line with the solution you want.

Answer (score 2):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -pe 's/TOTAL.{20}(.*)/sprintf "%s%s%s", "TOTAL", " "x20, $1/e' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would use perl for this:

```
perl -pe 'substr($_,20,8," "x8 ) if /TOTAL/' input-file
```

but I think what you really want is something like:

```
awk '/TOTAL/{ $2=""; $3="" } 1 ' input-file
```

However, if you need to keep the formatting the same, you can do:

```
awk '/TOTAL/{ printf( "%s%30s\n", $1, $4 ); next } 1' input-file
```

with the appropriate field width in the format string.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`

```
awk '/^TOTAL/{$0= substr($0, 1, 19)"        "substr($0,28, length($0))}1' file
```

Or if all lines have the same number of columns do

```
awk '/^TOTAL/{$0=sprintf("%s%27s", $1, $6)}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, answers using `sed`, `awk`, and `perl` but none using `bash`.  So, here goes:

```
while read line
do
    if [[ $line == TOTAL* ]];then
        extract=${line:19:8}
        echo "${line/$extract/        }"
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi

done << END
line1 with details 100 2566 1222
line2 with details 258 5874 5455
TOTAL text here    425 9589 8984
END
```

It is not perfect, if the numbers are duplicated on the same line then we will have issues.